# How to Debug ProxyFactoryBean Interceptor not firing

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I'm trying to use the MethodInterceptor and ProxyFactorBean to be able to produce audit information on a particular method.

I can see that the bean interceptedOpMethod is initialized, but it never gets called when originalOp is called.  I don't see any errors in the log.

Is there some debugging capability within Spring to be able to track down why it isn't getting called?

```
 <bean id="interceptedOpMethod" class="com.chunk.audit.CollectData" />

 <bean id="originalOp" class="com.chunk.calculate.Stats" />

 <bean id="interceptedOp" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="originalOp" />

    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>interceptedOpMethod</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you instantiating com.chunk.calculate.Stats?  If you create it via "new", then Spring never has the chance to inject the cut points into its instance methods.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This may be my problem.